# Rbenv install of ruby 2.7.2 fails with the error [make: *** [Makefile:271: miniruby] Error 1] on termux-rooted

Tags: ruby, linux, rbenv, termux

I am on android 7.1 running termux. I have recently installed rbenv to install ruby 2.7.2. Since the new ruby 3.0 release most of the tools have been broken. Ex:Metasploit. I have all the required dependencies. I have tried `rbenv install 2.7.2` and `RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--disable-install-doc rbenv install 2.7.2`. It gives me this error when I type rbenv install 2.7.2`
ERROR:

```
Downloading ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.2...

BUILD FAILED (Linux 3.10.49-gd9886247 using ruby-build 20210119)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.SccO9E
Results logged to /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.log

Last 10 log lines:
linking miniruby
rb_mjit_header.h updated
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: cont.o: in function `coroutine_initialize':
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.SccO9E/ruby-2.7.2/./coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:51: undefined reference to `makecontext'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: cont.o: in function `coroutine_initialize_main':
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.SccO9E/ruby-2.7.2/./coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:32: undefined reference to `getcontext'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: cont.o: in function `coroutine_transfer':
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.SccO9E/ruby-2.7.2/./coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:59: undefined reference to `swapcontext'
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:271: miniruby] Error 1
```

I have gave up after trying to fix this after 4 hours.
Here is the log file

```
compiling array.c
compiling mjit.c
WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/ruby: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x8000001
compiling coroutine/ucontext/Context.c
In file included from coroutine/ucontext/Context.c:14:                                                                                                                                coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:32:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'getcontext' with type 'int (ucontext_t *)' (aka 'int (struct ucontext *)') [-Wimplicit-function-dec
laration]                                                                                                                                                                                 getcontext(&context->state);                                                                                                                                                          ^
coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:32:5: note: include the header <setjmp.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'getcontext'                                                           coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:51:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'makecontext' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    makecontext(&context->state, (void(*)(void))coroutine_trampoline, 2, (void*)start, (void*)context);
    ^
coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:59:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'swapcontext' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    swapcontext(&current->state, &target->state);
    ^
3 warnings generated.
compiling enc/ascii.c
compiling enc/us_ascii.c
compiling enc/unicode.c                                                                                                                                                               compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
./revision.h unchanged
compiling version.c
1 warning generated.
building rb_mjit_header.h
linking miniruby
rb_mjit_header.h updated
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: cont.o: in function `coroutine_initialize':
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.SccO9E/ruby-2.7.2/./coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:51: undefined reference to `makecontext'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: cont.o: in function `coroutine_initialize_main':
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.SccO9E/ruby-2.7.2/./coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:32: undefined reference to `getcontext'
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ld: cont.o: in function `coroutine_transfer':
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/ruby-build.20210215164020.20674.SccO9E/ruby-2.7.2/./coroutine/ucontext/Context.h:59: undefined reference to `swapcontext'
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)                                                                                                    make: *** [Makefile:271: miniruby] Error 1
```

I have no idea what to do. I am a noob , So please explain what to do and THANKS in advance.